# How to find an Object Array contains an element or not?

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexing

I am working on Object Array I am able to get the elements till the no of elements exists.For example

`Object[] elements={"Apple","Orange","Grape","Mango","Banana"};`

I am able to get the elements by index but when i got beyond the index length.For instance here we have 5 elements last will be accessed by elements[4],but how to check elements[5],elements[6] exists or not

Comment: `elements.length` returns the size of the array.

Comment: I will be using this in a for loop so the size of array tend to vary.I need to just find whether the element at the index is containing a value or not.

Comment: @Karthik: Provide a better example of your code. `elements.length` also works in a loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
    Object[] elements = {"Apple","Orange","Grape","Mango","Banana"};

    Object obj = null;
    int elementsLength = elements.length;

    int i = 10;

    if (i < elementsLength) {
        obj = elements[i];
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops!.. Out of index!");
    }

    if (obj != null) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Your example is more complicated than necessary. e.g., initializing `i` with `0` right before setting it to `10` and declaring a variable `elementsLength` that is only used once...

Comment: @tuergeist Yes, I know. Because it is do-your-staff ready example with additional features.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use `elements.length` to find the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 4):

Ass Voo noted, you need to check the Array length, such as:

```
for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
  // Check elements[i] here.
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the new for loop syntax introduced with Java 5:

```
for(Object e : elements){
  // Check e here.
}
```

Still better, you could wrap the Array as a `List`, and use its `contains` method:

```
Arrays.asList(elements).contains("Strawberry"); // Will return false.
```

Answer (score 3):

Before getting an element by index, you always have to make sure that the index is valid. Either you know that the index exists because you created the array and knwo its length, or you don't know because you didn't create the array, and then you just have to check if the index is valid for the array:

```
if (index < array.length) {
    // the index is valid for this array. I can use array[index]
}
```

Most of the time, an array is used to iterate over all its elements, and you just iterate from 0 (inclusive) to the length of the array (exclusive):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // do something with array[i]
}
```

There is always something in an array of primitive types. An `int[]` array is filled with `int` values. If not initialized, it's filled with 0. A `boolean[]` array is filled with false by default.

An array of objects is, by default, filled with `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an array is an Object. That object contains a `public final` field called `length`. This field contains the length of the array (= number of elements).

So, to answer you question literally:

> how to check elements[5],elements[6] exists or not

By comparing the index you want to check with the arrays length.

```
public boolean doesIndexExist(Object[] array, int indexToCheck)
{
    return indexToCheck < array.length;
}
```

To use this in a loop, you can write a simple for loop, which always checks if the index stil is smaller than the array length.

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; ++index)
{

}
```

Comment: Your `doesIndexExist` is more complicated that just using `indexToCheck < array.length` as a one-liner

Comment: @tuergeist: I know. And I want to you to know that I **never** do it this way. But I just wrote it because the OP might understand it better this way. I don't know if it actually helped him a lot, but it was worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use length property of array to identify no of elements available. Even you can write method like this.

```
Object[] elements={"Apple","Orange","Grape","Mango","Banana"};
public boolean isElementExist(int index) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(index >= 0 && index < elements.length) {
       result = true;        
    }
    return result;
}
```